# How use rails wikedpdf gem with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I'm using the [wikedpdf gem](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) on a rails project to get my reports.

But to one report I need to use an ajax request

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'pdf',
        data: { ids: getIdsJavascriptMethod() },
        success(data) { $("#load-app").hide(); return false; },
        error(data) { $("#load-app").hide(); return false; }
      });
```

I'm calling the ajax reques wth a `link_to`

```
<%= link_to "PDF", "#", onclick: "pdf()", target: :_blank %>
```

But are rendering the same page **"#"** on a **_blank** target, how to render a PDF file using wikedpdf gem with an **ajax request**?

Comment: i think you need `remote: true` in your link_to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's opening a new tab because that's the default behavior of clicking a link with `target="_blank"`. Use `e.preventDefault()` first thing in your `pdf()` function to prevent this behavior.

```js
function pdf(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // make Ajax request
}
```

And replace "#" with the js call on link_to:

```rb
= link_to "PDF", "javascript:pdf()", target: :_blank
```

---

Or, better yet in IMO, add an id to your link event:

```rb
<%= link_to "PDF", "#", id: "pdf-link", target: :_blank %>
```

And listen to the click (code assumes you have jQuery loaded):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pdf-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    pdf();
  });
});
```

Comment: I try it but nothing changes

Comment: @gFontaniva if you want to open something in a new tab you have to do it via javascript with `window.open(pdfDocumentURL, '_blank');`